# Windows Azure behind NATed router

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am working on a project and am attempting to run a FTP daemon on an azure vm running the Technical Preview 2.  The Daemon reports that it is behind a NATed router, and as such I can not connect in via another means but the remote desktop connection. (I will be running other daemons on this server as well, and they also have this problem)

I need some way to access this router that my Azure server is behind to configure it to allow for the range of ports that i need to access.

The fine folks at MVA instructed me to ask here, so here I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to open the port (endpoint setting in the portal) to the virtual machine, so check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) out.

Also, make sure the local firewall isn't blocking that ftp port... I'm pretty sure it's off by default.

Comment: On the azure server, I have given the Daemon full access through the firewall.  I will check the endpoint settings and report back